# How can I implement this kind of functionality in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I have a combo page where first step customer select any of the soles of the shoes and next step to select skins(upper part of the shoes) which having must be select three skins.

Once completed the above mentioned steps, final add to cart page with the final price with specific discount.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality, you can either find an extension or it can be achieved by custom programming.

Below are the rough steps to achieve this using custom code:

1. Create a **custom module to manage sole and skins** in the admin panel.
2. In frontend, create a controller's action to allow customers to select sole.
3. **When the customer selects sole, save information in session** and take the customer to new controller's action where they can choose skins. Save this information too in the session.
4. After the selection is done, **create a product with custom options programmatically** with the information you just got from the customer in previous steps.
5. **Add the newly created product to customer's quote programmatically** and delete the session created in step #3.

**Note:** If you want to show a preview of the product to the customer, then you need to use some javascript framework to generate preview on the basis of above configurations.

Comment: Thank you !  can you please suggest any extension available for it .or please explain in details because i am newbie in magneto i don't have that much idea .